# Monitoring system clipboard changes in Dart on Linux

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, clipboard

I am working on a Dart application that needs to monitor the system clipboard for changes on Linux. I want to detect when the clipboard content is modified and perform certain actions based on the new content. I have searched for existing Dart packages, but I couldn't find a suitable one that specifically supports clipboard monitoring on Linux.

I am aware that on Linux, the xclip command-line tool can be used to access the clipboard. I want to implement clipboard monitoring in Dart by utilizing xclip or any other native Linux method.

I would like to know how I can achieve clipboard monitoring in Dart on Linux without relying on external packages like clipboard_manager. I prefer a solution that uses native Dart code or leverages existing Linux libraries/commands.

I would appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to implement clipboard monitoring in Dart on Linux.